# C# how to fill a datatable using Task

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

Basically I have a webpage that when I type into a box it causes a post back that I just want fill my datatable.   Howevr, i cannot for the life of me understanding how to fill this datatable using task.

Any help would be great!

```
protected void RadInput_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task<DataTable> mytab = myTable(simpleTextBox.Text);
        simpleGrid.DataSource = mytab;
        simpleGrid.DataBind();
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "refocus", "refocus()", true);
    }

    private async Task<DataTable> myTable(string searchClause)
    {
        DataTable myTab = new DataTable();
        myTab.Columns.Add("Results");
        for (int i = 0; i < myResults.Length; i++)
        {
            if (myResults[i].ToLower().StartsWith(searchClause.ToLower()))
            {
                DataRow dtRow = myTab.NewRow();
                dtRow[0] = myResults[i];
                myTab.Rows.Add(dtRow);

            }
        }

        return myTab;


    }



    private static string[] myResults = { "Apples", "Pears", "Bananas", "Oranges", "Advil", "Populate", "Bear" };
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bind a grid to a Task.
If you want to use Tasks you can use one of the following

```
simpleGrid.DataSource =await mytab; //You must mark the event as async
```

or

```
simpleGrid.DataSource =mytab.Result;
```

If you don't have an IO operation inside myTable() you can just return a DataTable and not a Task

You can learn more about Tasks here
[Task Parallel Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx)